# Construct Binary Search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

Construct Binary Search Tree in the following order:
JAN, MAR, JUN, FEB, JUL, MAY, APR, SEP, AUG, OCT, NOV, DEC.

How am I supposed to solve the problem? How do I know which is greater than whom?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see the help on how to write a question.  SO is not a homework or code-writing service.  You need to do that. If you run into a detail that's preventing you from getting your code working, then you can come back to ask for specific help.

Comment: nb: One approach to dealing with the order is to use a table mapping the month strings to integers 1 to 12. Then compare two months by looking up the respective two integers and comparing them.

Comment: The challenge should mention what the comparison is between items. Is FEB < AUG (because the month FEB occurs earlier in the year than AUG), or is FEB > AUG (because the letter "F" comes after "A").

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have something like this:

```
          JAN
         /   \
       FEB   MAR
              \
              MAY
              \
              APR
              \
              JUN
              \
              SEP
              \
              AUG
              \
              OCT
              \
              NOV
              \
              DEC
```

so, you would have to start by creating a new node for the root of the tree and setting its value to the first element in the list, which is "JAN" in this case.

For each subsequent element in the list, compare the element to the root node. If the element is less than the root node, add it as the left child of the root node. If the element is greater than the root node, add it as the right child of the root node.
Repeat this process for the newly added node, comparing it to its parent node and adding it as the left or right child as appropriate.

Comment: how do you know MARCH is greater than January?